# The problem of K-Means with non-convex function

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, clustering, k-means

In all articles I've read say "K-means is not converge with non-convex function".I just know that convex function is the function that able to find the global minimum. However , I do not understand how this relate to K-Means algorithm.

I need to ask

1. Which situation cause the non-convex problem ? (If possible please visualize it and show the equation)
2. In some articles say that the bad initialization( the poor seeds) cause the not-convex problem, How are they related?
3. I'm not quite sure the referred function is subject to which variables.Are that clusters and their centroid ?

---

Ok , It's my misunderstanding. K-Means is not converged with non-convex shape data set .Nothing relate with convex function,sorry.

Comment: "all articles" - can you name some? Because that statement does not make sense, as you do not apply k-means to a "(non-) convex function" but to points from R^d

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Correct me if I'm wrong tanawatl, but I believe OP is asking why the K-means optimization problem is non-convex.

Comment: That question is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463453/how-to-see-that-k-means-objective-is-convex